# Function defined in javascript file not able to called from jsp file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

When I enter my input and click on save button . on save button

```
jQuery("#changePassword").click(function() {
    requestToSaveChages()
});
```

It won't work. This is on .jsp file and `requestToSaveChages()` I have written in `.js` file.

Comment: What's your code in `requestToSaveChages()`?

Comment: Please add the HTML of your code and `requestToSaveChages` function.

Comment: I am making ajax call from that function and used alert() in that function.

Comment: Does the alert working for you?

Comment: No I am getting error on console like -   inputUserID=dsfdfdAA:331 Uncaught ReferenceError: requestToChangePassword is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (?inputUserID=dsfdfdAA:331)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (VM637 jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (VM637 jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: Make sure you have included your `JS file` inside `JSP` page . Could you show the structure of your `JSP` how and where you have include `JS`

Comment: Hi Manikant sir Thank you very much I forgot to import js file on jsp page. I had written above code in index.jsp and inside js folder my .js file was present so I imported like <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script> and it worked for Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @pooja glad to help.